# Drupal 8 "log in" form won't appear

Tags: drupal-8

Not sure what the heck I did, but after a day of logging in just fine to the Admin panel of my new D8 site, I am now (apparently) not permitted to access that page.  I was in the middle of making new content, saved it, and got "Access Denied."  When I went to log in, instead of reaching the /user/login window to input my credentials, I am just redirected to the main page.

I am sure this must be a simple setting that I goofed on, but not sure what it might have been.  I haven't changed anything with the .htaccess, settings.php, or any permissions.  Just doing content addition and things like minor css visual tweaks.

So interestingly, it seems this is only happening on Firefox, which (oddly) was the browser I was using the whole day.  If I switch to Chrome I can log in and edit content.  But Firefox (or other variants) simply zip me right to the home page, with nary a chance to enter my login credentials.

If you know what might be going on I'd love a tip.  Right now I'm totally locked out of the site, though I do have file manager access and can do PhpMyAdmin if necessary.

Thanks in advance for any help, tips, or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please clear(truncate) cache* tables via Phpmyadmin and try to login

Comment: I woke up, having done nothing overnight, and it now allows me to log in on Firefox, so I'm guessing it had to be cache-related.  Thank you for taking a moment to offer this.  I'll mark it correct.  If it happens again and this doesn't solve it I'll be back with more info/questions.  Cheers!